# Unix to Timezone Conversion, Offset element

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, posix, offset

I converted a UNIX timestamp to a human format (sorry I do not know the exact name of it) in a specific timezone (Africa/Algeria) and it evaluated to this: `2020-06-05 19:45:21+01:00`. I looked into the datetime module documentation and from what I understood the `+01:00`, it is the +/-HH:MM offset from the UTC.
What I do not understand is why it is returned with the datetime object given it is already converted to the indicated timezone?
Could someone explain it to me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIX timestamps (Unix time) represent time in seconds since the epoch, 1970-01-01 UTC. No time zone issues involved here. `datetime` objects on the other hand can be *naive* (not contain any time zone information) or time zone *aware*. What you have is a time zone aware `datetime` object - its string representation prints out as "2020-06-05 19:45:21+01:00". If it had been naive, it would only print "2020-06-05 19:45:21". The `repr` should also show you a specific time zone, e.g.

```
print(repr(dt_obj))
>>> datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 5, 19, 45, 21, tzinfo=tzfile('Africa/Algiers'))
```

The important point is that `2020-06-05 19:45:21+01:00` can be converted back to POSIX timestamp without ambiguity:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.fromisoformat("2020-06-05 19:45:21+01:00").timestamp()
# 1591382721.0
```

If it wasn't for the +01:00 (no `tzinfo`), Python would *assume* that the datetime object belongs in local time, i.e. OS setting; meaning that machines in different time zones would get a different timestamp. I'm on UTC+2, so I would get:

```
datetime.fromisoformat("2020-06-05 19:45:21").timestamp()
# 1591379121.0
```

which gives the same timestamp as

```
datetime.fromisoformat("2020-06-05 19:45:21+02:00").timestamp()
# 1591379121.0
```

The difference is that with the "+02:00" (`tzinfo` defined), it is obvious what is happening.